# PubNub - Search for a chat match (foreign language learning chat app)

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

I'm trying to make a foreign language chat app (because I love languages) that is similar to Omegle.com!

I'm making my chat application using [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/angularjs/chat-getting-started/) and AngularJS.

Basically, my chat app is designed like this:

1. First the user is presented with a screen of what language they can speak and what language they want to learn
2. Let's say I am an English speaker and I am learning German (HomeController)
3. They press the CHAT! button and goes to my ChatController
4. From here, the user is in a *queue* until a native speaker match to their learning language is found *(this is the part where I'm having the most trouble)*

Here are pictures to get a better idea: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZum9.jpg

Here is what I have so far:

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Linga!</title>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/semantic.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

        <!-- AngularJS and jQuery -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script
          src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
          crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>

        <!-- PubNub Service -->
        <script src="http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/pubnub-angular/pubnub-angular-4.0.2.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Underscore support -->
        <script src="js/vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>

        <!-- Scroll Glue -->
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue/master/src/scrollglue.js"></script>

        <!-- Semantic UI JS -->
        <script src="js/vendor/semantic.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="ChatApp">
        <div ng-view></div>

        <!-- App -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/ChatController.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using `ng-view` to route between my `HomeController.js` and `ChatController.js`.

> home.html View

```
<div id="background"></div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="ui container">
        <div class="ui center aligned segment glass">
            <h1 id="linga">Ling<span>a</span></h1>
            <form class="ui form" ng-submit="submit()" name="chatForm">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>I speak</label>
                    <select class="ui fluid dropdown" ng-model="selectedNative" ng-options="language.name for language in languages">
                        <option value="">Language</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Find someone</label>
                    <select class="ui fluid dropdown" ng-model="selectedLearning" ng-options="language.name for language in languages">
                        <option value="">Language</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button class="ui button" id="submit" type="submit">CHAT</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the user selects what language they are native in and what they are learning. And then the chat button is pressed which goes to the `submit()` function in my `HomeController.js`.

> HomeController.js

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$location', 'languageService', function($scope, $location, languageService){
    //$scope.hello = "hi!";
    $scope.languages = [
    {
        name:'German',
        flag:'img/flags/de.png'
    },
    {
        name:'French',
        flag:'img/flags/fr.png'
    },
    {
        name:'English',
        flag:'img/flags/us.png'
    },
    {
        name:'Portuguese',
        flag:'img/flags/br.png'
    },
    {
        name:'Persian',
        flag:'img/flags/ir.png'
    },
    {
        name:'Russian',
        flag:'img/flags/ru.png'
    },
    {
        name:'Swedish',
        flag:'img/flags/se.png'
    },
    {
        name:'Turkish',
        flag:'img/flags/tr.png'
    },
    {
        name:'Spanish',
        flag:'img/flags/es.png'
    },
    {
        name:'Italian',
        flag:'img/flags/it.png'
    }
    ];

    $scope.submit = function(){
        languageService.setNative($scope.selectedNative.name);
        languageService.setLearning($scope.selectedLearning.name);
        $location.path("/chat");
    }

}]);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

Here the `submit()` function in my `HomeController.js` puts the native and learning language information in my `languageService` so that my `ChatController.js` can use the information.

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module('ChatApp', ['ngRoute', 'pubnub.angular.service', 'luegg.directives']);

app.service('languageService', function(){
    var languages = {
        nativeLanguage: '',
        learningLanguage: ''
    };

    return{
        setNative: setNative,
        setLearning: setLearning,
        getLanguages: getLanguages
    };

    function getLanguages(){
        return languages;
    };

    function setNative(nativeLanguage){
        languages.nativeLanguage = nativeLanguage;
    };

    function setLearning(learningLanguage){
        languages.learningLanguage = learningLanguage;
    };
});

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller:'HomeController',
        templateUrl:'views/home.html'
    })
    .when('/chat', {
        controller:'ChatController',
        templateUrl:'views/chat.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

This service in `app.js` puts the information attained from `HomeController.js` and makes them available for controllers.

> ChatController.js

```
app.controller('ChatController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'languageService', 'Pubnub', 
    function($scope, $rootScope, languageService, Pubnub){
    $scope.languages = languageService.getLanguages();
    $scope.channel = 'messages-channel';
    // Generating a random uuid between 1 and 100 using an utility function from the lodash library.         
    $scope.uuid = _.random(100).toString();
    Pubnub.init({
        publish_key: 'demo',
        subscribe_key: 'demo',
        uuid: $scope.uuid
    });

    // Send the messages over PubNub Network
    $scope.sendMessage = function() {
       // Don't send an empty message 
       if (!$scope.messageContent || $scope.messageContent === '') {
            return;
        }
        Pubnub.publish({
            message: {
                content: $scope.messageContent,
                sender_uuid: $scope.uuid,
                date: new Date()
            },
            channel: $scope.channel
        });
        // Reset the messageContent input
        $scope.messageContent = '';

    }

    $scope.messages = [];

    // Subscribing to the ‘messages-channel’ and trigering the message callback
    Pubnub.subscribe({
        channel: $scope.channel,
        withPresence: true,
        triggerEvents: ['callback']
    });

    // Listening to the callbacks
    $rootScope.$on(Pubnub.getMessageEventNameFor($scope.channel), function(ngEvent, m){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.messages.push(m);
        });
    });
}]);
```

> chat.html View

```
<div class="main-chat">
    <div class="ui container">
        <div class="chat-box ui segment" id="style-3" scroll-glue>
            <p>Searching for a {{languages.learningLanguage}} speaker ...</p>
            <ul>
                 <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
                   <strong>Anonymous {{message.sender_uuid}}: </strong>
                   <span>{{message.content}}</span>
                 </li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
        <div class="chat-field ui segement">
            <div class="ui form">
                <textarea ng-enter="sendMessage()" ng-model="messageContent"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And so here's where I'm stuck. For example, if I'm learning German, I want my chat app to stay in queue until a German native is found using the variables I made in my `languageService`. When it is found, they go into the chat and start learning languages!

My logic:

1. Need to find out who's currently using my app (for example 1,000 people)
2. Then I search in some sort of *array* for a native speaker I want to learn with
3. The most immediate match will terminate the loop (or listener) and go straight into chat

I did try adding `Pubnub.addListener` to my `ChatController.js` but it says that `Pubnub.addListener is not a function` error.

Tackled this problem for many hours reading a lot of tutorials on PubNub, but I can't figure it out at all.

Thank you so much for your help. I tried to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: First, `addListener` not a function must mean that `Pubnub` object is out of scope (it must be) but don't have further insight at this time. For your list of available native speakers, just create a channel for each language: `native.german`, `native.french`, etc. As users logon, have them subscribe to the proper `native.<lang>` channel. You can use `hereNow` to get the list of active/online native speakers for that language. And use PubNub Functions to do the translation in realtime without hitting your server to do that work: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks-catalog/multilingual-chat

Comment: We saw your inquiry in our private support. We'll address in more detail there and share details back here as an official answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, addListener not a function must mean that PubNub object is out of scope (it must be) but don't have further insight at this time.

For your list of available native speakers, just create a channel for each language: `native.german`, `native.french`, etc. As users logon, have them subscribe to the proper `native.<lang>` channel.

You can use hereNow to get the list of active/online native speakers for that language.

And use [PubNub Functions to do the translation in realtime](http://pubnub.com/docs/blocks-catalog/multilingual-chat) without hitting your server to do that work.